# I want to simultaneously write and read numeric values in two different python scripts

Tags: python

I am designing a traffic light signal based on image processing. I get the traffic congestion as a numeric value. I am using a RaspberryPi. I have to design a working model. Now the problem is I use `time.sleep()` to generate delays in the switching of lights. But during this time I cant do any other processing. so I want to write the numeric values some where and access them in a separate script.

Comment: Use python multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zindarod on multiprocessing, especially during the proof of concept phase.  If you hope to hook this up at scale then I'd recommend a different system architecture.  Each raspberry pi is a client which communicates with a server.  This will help logically abstract tasks and make it easier to integrate with celery or other asynch task management tools.